# Import HTML tag from external file which contains PHP code

Tags: php, html

I have two files index.php and template.html. In the template file I have a div, which contains some PHP code inside. What I am trying to achieve is to pull the div from template including everything inside and insert it to my main index page. I managed to do so, but only if there is no PHP code inside the div. If however there is any PHP included I see something like this "saveHTML($snippet[1]) ?>;" instead of full PHP code block. Could you please explain the reason why I am not able to move the div including PHP codes.

index.php file

```
<?php 
//some basic stuff such as new DOMDocument(); loadHTMLFile and so on

$post = $posts->query("//div[contains(@class, 'post')]");

?>

<body>
    <?php echo $templates->saveHTML($post[0]);?>
</body>
```

template.html file

```
<div class="post">
    <?php echo $examples->saveHTML($snippet[1]) ?>;
</div>
```

Comment: The browser interprets `<?php echo $examples->` as an HTML tag. This "tag" is unknown to the browser, so it ignores it and displays only the "contents".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in a simpler manner

first in template.html please replace your dynamic content with `%%posts%%`
i.e, 
template.html

```
<div class="post">
    %%posts%%
</div>
```

then in your index.php get contents of template using  file_get_contents
after that replace it with your dynamic code like as below

```
 $htmlFile            = 'template.html'; 
 $yourDynamicContents = 'Replace your dynamice msg here';
 $contents = file_get_contents($htmlFile); 
 $contents = str_replace('%%posts%%', $yourDynamicContents, $contents);
```

`$contents` has whole page...you can either echo or send mail with that template or even pass to print pdf etc

the above will do it simply and clean.
P.S you can replace anything in $yourDynamicContents whether its css,html,js

Hope the above answer helps 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the content of your template file via file_get_contents? Then maybe you can extract your div with substr() using strpos()